# AngularJS compiled code staying "in the back"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-compile

I've noticed what seems to be a bug for me, but is probably more me misusing the `$compile` service in AngularJS : I have a directive called "dynamic" that compiles angularjs code and shows it into a div. The code that I compile in that case contains `ng-controllers` and those controllers are listening on events. The problem is that apparently controllers aren't "dead" after being replaced, because controllers that should be vanished still react to events (like `$routeChangeSuccess` or any other event).
Here is a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YIMGKtLkHGvrOudrCPn7?p=preview) that shows the problem.
Let's see an example code of my problem :

**The directive I'm using** :

```
app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
                element.html(html);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**The main controller, followed by the controllers that I include:**

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dynamicContent = "Default content";

  $scope.firstButton = function() {
    $scope.dynamicContent = "<div ng-controller='FirstCtrl'>The div from first button</div>";
  }

  $scope.secondButton = function() {
    $scope.dynamicContent = "<div ng-controller='SecondCtrl'>The div from second button</div>";
  }

  $scope.checkButton = function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('checkEvent');
  }
});

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('checkEvent', function() {
    alert(1);
  });

});
app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('checkEvent', function() {
    alert(2);
  });
});
```

Now if I call `firstButton()` then `secondButton()` then `checkButton()`, instead of receiving only the `alert(2)`, I receive two alerts. If I hit buttons 1/2/1/2/1/2/1/2 it's going to show me as many alerts as buttons I've clicked.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks, hilnius

Comment: It seems like your `dynamic` directive does what `ng-include` does ... except that `ng-include` (my assumption) is probably using $scope.$destroy() to get rid of scopes created by the dynamic templates it has loaded.

Comment: I cannot use ng-include because what I want to show is the result of a post request. Should I use manually $scope.$destroy in the right scope before changing the dynamic variable ?

Comment: Yes, I'd head in that direction. Admittedly, I've always relied on Angular disposing of controllers/scopes for me, so I don't know how successful this approach will be. Perhaps seeing what [ng-include does](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L186) while creating/destroying scopes might be helpful.

Comment: I realized after posting what your intentions were, so the $templateCache doesn't really apply, but it may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your really close. First I'll give you what your probably looking to do since I do not know your intentions for the $compile service. Then I'll explain why you don't need the $compile service for this particular instance since your effectively duplicating ng-include.

What your probably looking to do:

The key to using directives (especially when attempting to "$compile" dynamic content is ensuring your know what scope is passed where. For most of the directives built into angularjs, angular automatically handles creation (via [scope.$new()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24new) ) and destruction (via [scope.$destroy()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24destroy) ). Since you are not explicitly '$destroy'-ing the scopes they will not be removed. Another problem is that your directly attaching the "dynamic" directive to the current scope without creating a child scope or an isolate scope in the directive (via $new):

[Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gyTTYlRJToffXggPO8bP?p=preview)

```
app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var curScope = null,
              curEle = null;

          function removeOld(){
            if( curScope ){
              curScope.$destroy();
              curScope = null;
              curEle.remove();
              curEle = null;
            }
          }

            scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
                removeOld();
                curScope = scope.$new(); //creates child scope (not isolate)
                //probably should do some proper escaping here see $sce service
                curEle = angular.element( html );
                if( !curEle.length ){
                  curEle = angular.element('<span>'+html+'</span>');
                }
                $compile( curEle )(curScope);
                element.append( curEle );
            });
        }
    };
});
```

What you probably should do:

For some small templates like this you probably should consider putting them into the $templateCache (via put as shown in the plunkr below) so that any request for the template can automatically load it. You also have to consider some other things like 'is the html properly sanitized?' or 'do I want my content animated properly?'. These things are automatically handled in ng-include which it almost seems like your trying to copy.

[Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4uZ5hcSQaL7jLcuJhWMF?p=preview)

```
app.run(function( $templateCache ){
  $templateCache.put("btn_default.html", "Default content");
  $templateCache.put("btn_one.html", "<div ng-controller='FirstCtrl'>The div from first button</div>");
  $templateCache.put("btn_two.html", "<div ng-controller='SecondCtrl'>The div from second button</div>");
})
```

Now all you have to do is use the pre-built [ng-include directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) like so:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
      <div class="btn btn-default" ng-click="firstButton()">First button</div>
      <div class="btn btn-default" ng-click="secondButton()">Second button</div>
      <div class="btn btn-default" ng-click="checkButton()">Check events</div>
      <div ng-include="dynamicContent"></div>
</div>
```

[ng-include source to help you out](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L170)

Hope this helps with a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helps. The second part also helps but is the cache being cleared automatically ? (to avoid memory leaks).
Also, your first plunkr is the same as the second, you may want to correct that for later readers

Comment: Good to hear, the links are different for me, not sure what's going on there. You should be able to use the [$cacheFactory methods](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) and use $templateCache.remove('btn_default.html') for example. Also don't forgot to mark an answer as the best one here on SO :).

Comment: I have one more question : if I'm not using a controller but just directives and {{}} in my compiled code will it be garbage-collected automatically or should I destroy it manually ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by {{}}, but if you call $destroy on the scope and .remove() on any jquery element it will be removed correctly.